# how to keep stack trace in workflow foundation 4

Tags: exception, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow(xaml) in WF4 and there is a code activity which calls external module (e.g. mapper). All exceptions are catched in the first layer (e.g. service layer). Service layer executes workflow by calling Invoke on WorkflowInvoker.  When mapper throws exception, this exception is catched in the service layer, but I lost stack trace from the mapper. The stack trace is comming from WorkflowInvoker.Invoke..

Is there any way how can I keep the stack trace from the mapper?

here is a schema of layers:

Service Layer -> Worklfow.Invoke -> (XAML: Code activity -> Mapper)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://neovolve.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/87888#1420890

I run a "hack" in there to get the thrown exception to preserve the stack trace.